# Best practice to refresh an EF5 result from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, reload

What is the best way to refresh data in Entity Framework 5? I've got an WPF application showing statistics from a database where data is changing all the time. Every 10 seconds the application is updating the result but the default behaviour for EF seems to be to cache the previous results. I would thus like a way to invalidate the previous results so a new set of data can be loaded.

The context of interest is defined in the following way:

```
public partial class MyEntities: DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Stat> Stats { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

After some reading I was able to find a few approaches, but I have no idea of how efficient these ways are and if they come with downsides.

- Create a new instance of the entities object

  ```
  using (var db = new MyEntities())
  { 
      var stats = from s in db.Stats ...
  }
  ```

  This works but feels inefficient because there are many other places where data is retrieved, and I don't want to reopen a new connection every time I need some data. Wouldn't it be more efficient to keep the connection open and do it another way?
- Call `refresh` on the `ObjectContext`

  ```
  var stats = from s in db.Stats ...
  ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, stats );
  ```

  This also assumes I'm extracting ObjectContext from the dbContext in this way:

  ```
  private MyEntities db = null;
  private ObjectContext ObjectContext
  {
      get
      {
          return ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
      }
  }
  ```

  This is the solution I'm using as it is now. It seems simple. But I read somewhere that ObjectContext nowadays isn't directly accessible in DbContext because the EF team doesn't think that anyone would need it, and that you can do all things you need directly in DbContext. This makes me think that maybe this is not the best way to do it, or?
- I know there is a `reload` method of `dbContext.Entry` but since I'm not reloading a single entity but rather retrieve a list of entities, I don't really know if this way will work. If I get 5 stat objects in the first query, save them in a list and do a `reload` on them when it's time to update, I might miss out others that have been added to the list on the database. Or have I completely misunderstood the `reload` method? Can I do a reload on a `DbSet`specified in `MyEntities`?

There are a number of questions above but what I mainly want to know is **what is the best practice in EF5 for asking the same query to the database over and over again?** It might very well be something that I haven't discovered yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, and even if it seems counter intuitive, the first option is the correct one, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647912/why-re-initiate-the-dbcontext-when-using-the-entity-framework)

`DbContext` are design to have short lifespans, hence their instantiation cost is quite low compared to the cost of reloading everything, it's mostly due to things like caching, and their data loading designs in general.

That's also why EF works so "naturally" well with ASP .NET MVC, since the `DbContext` is instantiated at each request.

That doesn't mean you have to create `DbContext` all over the place of course, in your context, using a `DbContext` per update operation (the one happening every 10secs) seems good enough, if during that operation you would need to delete a particular row, for example, you would pass the `DbContext` around, not create a new one.

Comment: After having read your link, and some other links, I start to understand more of why it might be better to not keep an instance of DbContext for too long. I didn't know it was caching all the changes and those can be quite many in an application being run all day long. Thanks for your answer...

Comment: @Ohlin my pleasure, a trick of mind I like to use with DBContext, is to think of its usage as it was a request for an ASP.NET MVC action, even in WPF, helps getting a good idea of the usage scope of a single DbContext object.