# AutoMapper.Collections, EFCore - using short living DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, dbcontext

I try to use [AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore) to map my objects. All is working fine if I use the same DbContext all the time.

The problem is that there is no possibility to reject all cached objects in DbContext. Yes I did a search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46205114/2729609) post but it doesn't work. I don't realy understand the problem but I bet it is because I only detach the container object. There is no way without complex algorithms to traverse all objects to detach them all.

This is the currently working code (very simplyfied):

```
using var ctx = this.DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
var dtoProject = await ctx.Set<DtoProject>().Include(item => item.Jobs).FirstAsync();

var p = this.Mapper.Map<Project>(dtoProject);
var j = new Job(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant(), $"Job {p.Jobs.Count + 1}");

p.Jobs.Add(j);

await ctx.Set<DtoProject>().Persist(this.Mapper).InsertOrUpdateAsync(p);
await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This code reuses `ctx` at `SaveChangesAsync()` which is working as expected.

But this leads to a `DbContext` instance that is very long living because it has to be alive as long as the business objects are in use. This doesn't sound like a real problem but I'm not able to invalidate objects in `DbContext` to force a reload if needed.

It seams that the way to go is to have a short living `DbContext` instance. Sounds good. I changed the code above so that a separate method is loading the business object and a new context is used to save the changes.

This simplyfied code shows the changes:

```
using var ctx = this.DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
var dtoProject = await ctx.Set<DtoProject>().Include(item => item.Jobs).FirstAsync();

var p = this.Mapper.Map<Project>(dtoProject);
var j = new Job(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant(), $"Job {p.Jobs.Count + 1}");

p.Jobs.Add(j);

using var tmpCtx = this.DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
await tmpCtx.Set<DtoProject>().Persist(this.Mapper).InsertOrUpdateAsync(p);
await tmpCtx.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The only change is a new `DbContext` called `tmpCtx` used to store the changed value.

But this code throws a `DbUpdateException` that told me a UNIQUE constraint violation for `jobs.id`. The 'container' instance `p` seams to be accepted but the contained job instances seam to fail.

**How to fix that?**

The following code shows the automapper configuration and object declarations:

```
private IMapper CreateMapper()
{
    var mapperCfg = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddExpressionMapping();
        cfg.AddCollectionMappers();

        cfg.CreateMap<Job, DtoJob>()
            .EqualityComparison((blo, dto) => blo.Id == dto.Id)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.ParentId, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Parent, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
        cfg.CreateMap<DtoJob, Job>()
            .EqualityComparison((dto, blo) => dto.Id == blo.Id)
            .ForCtorParam("id", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForCtorParam("name", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForSourceMember(src => src.ParentId, opt => opt.DoNotValidate())
            .ForSourceMember(src => src.Parent, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());

        cfg.CreateMap<Project, DtoProject>()
            .EqualityComparison((blo, dto) => blo.Id == dto.Id)
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Jobs, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Jobs));
        cfg.CreateMap<DtoProject, Project>()
            .EqualityComparison((dto, blo) => dto.Id == blo.Id)
            .ForCtorParam("id", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForCtorParam("name", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Jobs, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Jobs));
    });
    mapperCfg.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    return mapperCfg.CreateMapper();
}

public class Job
{
    public Job(string id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }
}

public class Project
{
    public Project(string id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

[Table("jobs")]
public class DtoJob
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column("parent_id")]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Parent))]
    [Required]
    public string ParentId { get; set; }

    public DtoProject Parent { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("projects")]
public class DtoProject
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<DtoJob> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

This all is a very simplyfied test code to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work. The steps are the following:

- Load:

  - Create a `DbContext` instance
  - Load the DTO and map it to business logic instance
  - Reject the `DbContext` instance
- Modify the business logic instance (add/modify/remove children)
- Save:

  - Create a `DbContext` instance
  - Load the DTO that corresponds to the business object by key into `DbSet`. The return value doesn't matter. We only need to know about this object.
  - Save the changed business logic instance using `InsertOrUpdate`.

This performs a load operation that shouldn't be needed but I didn't find an other solution.

The simplyfied code is:

```
var p = (await this.LoadAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
// null handling omitted
var j = new Job(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B").ToUpperInvariant(), $"Job {p.Jobs.Count + 1}");

p.Jobs.Add(j);
p.Jobs.RemoveAt(0);

await this.SaveAsync(p);
```

This uses the following methods:

```
private async Task<IList<Project>> LoadAsync(Expression<Func<Project, bool>> filter = null)
{
    using var ctx = this.DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    IQueryable<DtoProject> query = ctx.Set<DtoProject>().Include(item => item.Jobs);
    if (!(filter is null))
    {
        query = query.Where(this.Mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<DtoProject, bool>>>(filter));
    }

    var resultDtos = await query.ToListAsync();
    var result = resultDtos.Select(this.Mapper.Map<Project>).ToList();
    return result;
}

private async Task SaveAsync(Project project)
{
    using var ctx = this.DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    await ctx.Set<DtoProject>().FindAsync(p.Id == project.Id);
    await ctx.Set<DtoProject>().Persist(this.Mapper).InsertOrUpdateAsync(projectToStore);
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The main advantage of this solution is that the `DbContext` instances are very short living. They are only used to load and save the objects. The lifetime of the business logic objects doesn't have any effect to the `DbContext` instances.

That's the approach I'll try now, hoping it will solve all the problems.