# EF Core Stored Procedure FromSqlRaw Does Not Give Updated Values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

When running a procedure on EF Core 3 using `FromSqlRaw` that updates values in the table, EF **DOES NOT** return the updated values when I query the database for those changed values.

I have been able to reproduce this behavior.  To reproduce create a new console app c# with .net core 3.1.

Copy paste the code below into your main Program.cs file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EfCoreTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // testing proc
            var dbContext = new TestContext();
            var tables = dbContext.TestTables.ToList();
            var updated = dbContext.TestTables
                .FromSqlRaw("execute testProc @Id=@Id, @Comments=@Comments", new object[]
                {
                    new SqlParameter("Id", 1),
                    new SqlParameter("Comments", "testing comments 2"),
                })
                .ToList();
            var again = dbContext.TestTables.ToList();
        }
    }


    public class TestTable
    {
        public int TestTableId { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TestTable> TestTables { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True");
        }
    }
}
```

Ensure that the following packages are installed:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
```

Change your connection string if necessary.

Run `dotnet ef migrations add initial`

Run `dotnet ef database update`

Run the following code in your db:

```sql
drop procedure if exists testProc
go
create procedure testProc
@Id int,
@Comments nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    update dbo.TestTables
    set Comment = @Comments
    where TestTableId = @Id;

    select * from dbo.TestTables;
end

go


INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTables]
(Comment) VALUES ('Test Comment');
```

So when you run the Main program on debug and put a breaker, you'll notice that NONE of the objects return values that were updated by the procedure when go to inspect it.  While in debug if you run a select statement on the table you will see that the "Comment" field is indeed updated.

Why is this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205114/how-to-refresh-an-entity-framework-core-dbcontext

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not specific to `FromSql`, but the way EF Core (all versions) [tracking queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) work.

Here is an excerpt from EF Core [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works) documentation topic:

> The following is a high level overview of the process each query goes through.
>
> 1. The LINQ query is processed by Entity Framework Core to build a representation that is ready to be processed by the database provider
>
>    - The result is cached so that this processing does not need to be done every time the query is executed
> 2. The result is passed to the database provider
>
>    - The database provider identifies which parts of the query can be evaluated in the database
>    - These parts of the query are translated to database specific query language (for example, SQL for a relational database)
>    - One or more queries are sent to the database and the result set returned (results are values from the database, not entity instances)
> 3. For each item in the result set
>
>    - If this is a tracking query, EF checks if the data represents an entity already in the change tracker for the context instance 
>        If so, the existing entity is returned
>        If not, a new entity is created, change tracking is setup, and the new entity is returned

Note the last bullet. What they do is basically an implementation of the so called *client wins* strategy (as opposed to *database wins* which you are looking for), and currently there is no way of changing that other than using *no-tracking* query.

In your example, insert `AsNotTracking()` somewhere in the queries (before `ToList`, after `dbContext.TestTables` - it really doesn't matter because it applies to the whole query), or just

```c#
dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

and now you'll see the updated values (from your SP call or from other sessions to the same database).

Comment: Ok, so I was aware of no tracking, and new it had something to do with how ef is caching results.  I used `AsNoTracking` on the wrong query and that's when I decided to ask the question.  Thank you for your answer and that high level excerpt.  My tests for my implementation are now passing.  However this does raise a design issue for me, whether `AsNoTracking` for most db queries returning results from repositories should be standard within the context of my project.

Comment: This was the answer to my problems as well, despite not making any changes, the results of my Stored procedure I was executing weren't updated inside of a loop until I added .AsNoTracking().ToList()