# Entity Framework Core does not load fresh data from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a Blazor Server App and I use the following code to add data to the database (using service repository):

```
async Task<string> ISoftwareSectionUserService.SetSoftwareSectionPermissions(Dictionary<string, string> softwareSections, int userId)
{
    try
    {
        var newUserSoftwareSections = new List<UserSoftwareSection>();
    
        var selectedItemsToDelete = await _sqliteContext.UserSoftwareSections.Where(x => x.UserRef == userId).ToListAsync();
    
        await _sqliteContext.BulkDeleteAsync(selectedItemsToDelete);
        await _sqliteContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
        foreach (var item in softwareSections)
        {
            var selectedSectionUser = await _sqliteContext.UserSoftwareSections
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserRef == userId && x.SoftwareSectionRefNavigation.SectionName == item.Key);//Key is section name
            var selectedSection = await _sqliteContext.SoftwareSections.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.SectionName == item.Key);//Value is permision string
    
            if (selectedSectionUser == null)
            {
                var userSoftwareSection = new UserSoftwareSection
                {
                    UserRef = userId,
                    SectionRef = (int)selectedSection?.SectionId,
                    Permissions = item.Value
                };
 
                newUserSoftwareSections.Add(userSoftwareSection);
            }
        }
        await _sqliteContext.BulkInsertAsync(newUserSoftwareSections, config => config.BatchSize = 100);
        await _sqliteContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ServiceResultModel<string> { Succeed = true });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ServiceResultModel<string> { Succeed = false, Message = (ex.Message + "\\ " + ex.InnerException) });
    }
}
```

And, I use the following codes to load data from database:

```
async Task<string> ISoftwareSectionUserService.GetUserSoftwareSections(int userId)
{
    try
    {
        var softwareSectionsList = await _sqliteContext.UserSoftwareSections.Include(x => x.SoftwareSectionRefNavigation).Where(x => x.UserRef == userId).ToListAsync();
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        };
    
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ServiceResultModel<List<UserSoftwareSection>> { Succeed = true, Data = softwareSectionsList }, settings);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ServiceResultModel<string> { Succeed = false, Message = (ex.Message + "\\ " + ex.InnerException) });
    }
}
```

When I loaded the data for the first time, it is based on database enries. But, when I add data to the database using `SetSoftwareSectionPermissions` and try to load them using `GetUserSoftwareSections`, the last data is shown, not the actual data in database (It shows database data only after page reload).
I studied some posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205114/how-to-refresh-an-entity-framework-core-dbcontext) and tried to reload `SqliteContext`. But when I reload database using `await _sqliteContext.Entry(softwareSectionsList).ReloadAsync();`, there is an error saying:

> The entity type 'List' was not found. Ensure that
> the entity type has been added to the model.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used `AsNoTracking()` in the Linq query and the problem solved.